# DataTable Ajax Nested List

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am returning a nested list of json from an Ajax call and would like to populate my data table with this. F
or example: In my C# Class:

```
public class Product_Browser : Json_Response
{

    public List<PRODUCT_TABLE> ProductData { get; set; }
    public List<ProductPlans> ProductPlan { get; set; }
}
```

Javascript function:

```
$dtBrowser = $(dtElementID).dataTable({
            filter: false,
            
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            responsive: true,

            ajax: {
                url: _Url,
                type: "GET",
                "dataSrc": function (jsonObj) {
                    console.log(jsonObj)             
                    return jsonObj
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "ProductData.ProductKey", title:"Key", visible: true },
                { data: "ProductPlan.PlanID", title: "Id", visible: true },
            
            ],
            order: [[1, "desc"]],
            
        });
    }
```

Now when i log the jsonObj it is valid JSON, but in my columns, data I don't know the correct way of accessing the two different lists of objects. I am able to do it for one list by changing the dataSrc to `return jsonObj.ProductData` but I need both pieces of data.

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "ProductData": [
        {
            "ProductKey": 102234,
            "ProductID": "TEST1",
            
        },
        {
            "ProductKey": 102310,
            "ProductID": "TEST2",
            
        },
        {
            "ProductKey": 102319,
            "ProductID": "TEST3",
        },
    ],
    "ProductGrabBagPlan": [
        {
            "PlanID": 1,
            "ProductKey": 102234
        },
        {
            "PlanID": 2,
            "ProductKey": 102310
        },
        {
            "PlanID": 3,
            "ProductKey": 102319
        },
        
    ],
    "Success": true,
    "Messages": [],
}
```

Comment: Each DataTable requires a single entry point for the array of objects (or array of arrays) it will use to build its table rows. You have 2 entry points (as you note in the question). The solution for this is to (a) change the structure of the JSON you return from the Ajax call; or (b) use your `function (jsonObj) { ... }` to re-arrange the `jsonObj` data using JavaScript. Instead of `return jsonObj` you will `return myRearrangedData` - which will contain one array (of objects, in your case).